# javascript 2 browsers 2 different values

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome, firefox

This is the success callback of a jQuery ajax function:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.error==1){
        $("#error").show();
    }else{
        console.log("sucess");
        //window.location=staticData.main;
    }
}
```

this is the json that im getting from the server:

```
{"error":1}
```

on Chrome I get an error but on firefox it always shows success.

Comment: try console.log(data.error); and see whats the result in Firefox.

Comment: on ff its undifined, how come is it possible?

Comment: better give the link so we can see

Comment: Could be differences in javascript's automatic type juggling. Try `if(parseInt(data.error)==1)` or `if(Number(data.error)==1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's a json object or just a string representing a json object??

I would try this:

```
data = JSON.parse( data ) || data;
console.log( data ); // this should be now a json object
if(data.error==1){
   $("#error").show();
}else{
   console.log("sucess");
}
```

Hope this helps, alternatively you could create a jsbin with the actual ajax response in a variable and we could help you figure this out. Cheers!

Comment: it was indeed the case, that code worked.
tho i replaced it with 
    
    dataType: "json"

as it says in the jquery documentation it should parse the data acording to the mime type of the response, that is not happening in the ff browser... thank you very mutch